# Extra space in the bottom of a parent block element

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

I have a parent element which is a block and so is the child element. The child has fixed dimensions where as the parent has none. yet there is an extra space at the bottom of the parent div. Can someone tell me where the extra space from? thanks in advance.

**PUG**

```
article.parent
  div.text-align
```

**SASS**

```
.parent
    border: 10px solid black
    text-align: center

.text-align
    display: inline-block
```

[Code-Pen](https://codepen.io/ganesh-kaniarasu/pen/oVEgZp)

[Check Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVgwp.png)

Comment: Before you say it's not a duplicate because it's not an image - it's the same for all inline / inline block elements

Answer (score 0):

Please add vertical-align: top;. please check below example code.

```css
.parent
    border: 10px solid black
    text-align: center

.text-align
    display: inline-block
    vertical-align: top
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Can you also explain why there is extra space to begin with?